# Change column order using media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

What I'm trying to do is to put the right column next to the left column using media query (right now it is next to the center column). The right column should also have left margin 10px (as the screen size shrinks) as it is in the example.
I add position: absolute; right: 8px; to .right but it doesnt work the way I need.
Thank You.

```css
div {
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#header {
    height: 52px;
    width: calc(100% - 16px);
    background-color: #B2D490;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
}
h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 27px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0px;
    color: #00457D;
}
.left {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #C7E6FF;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 64px;
    margin-right: calc(50% - 450px);
}
.middle {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #DEF0FF;
    margin-top: 64px;
    float: left;
}
.right {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #C7E6FF;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 64px;
}
#footer {
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #57C449;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
p {
    color: #00579E;
}
#footer p {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    line-height: 35px;
}
span {
    color: #D4EBFF;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  body {
      width: 95%;
  }
   .left {
      width: 60%;
      margin-right: 0;
   }
   .middle {
      width: 60%;
      margin-top: 10px;
     clear: both;
   }
   .right {
      width: calc(40% - 10px);
      margin-top: 10px;

  
      
   }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
  <title>My Resume</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="header">
     <h1>My <span>Resume</span></h1>
 </div>
 <div class="left">
     <h2>Left Column</h2>
         <ul>
             <p>Some Text</p>
             <p>Some Text</p>
         </ul>
 </div>
  <div class="middle">
     <h2>Сenter Column</h2>
         <ul>
                <li><p>Some Text</p></li>
                <li><p>Some Text</p></li>
        </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
     <h4>Right Column</h4>
         <ul>
             <p>Some Text</p>
             <p>Some Text</p>
        </ul>
 </div>
 <div style="clear:both; border:none; border-radius: none;"></div>
 <div id="footer">
     <p>© 2015 Me - the Programmer</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by making a few changes to your CSS and HTML:

- Move the `.middle` `div` after the `.right` `div` in HTML
- Change `margin-top: 10px;` to `margin-top: 64px;` on `.right` in the media query

This works because `.middle` is set to `float: left;` which will push it to the left of its container until it hits another floated element (in this case `.left`). `.right` is set to `float: right;` which will push it to the right of its container.

> **How floats are positioned**
>
> As mentioned above, when an element is floated it is taken out of the
>   normal flow of the document. It is shifted to the left or right until
>   it touches the edge of its containing box or another floated element.

*float (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)*

When the media query is in effect `.middle` is set to `clear: both;`, as it is after both `.left` and `.right` in HTML it will be placed on a new line clearing both floated elements.

```css
div {
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#header {
  height: 52px;
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  background-color: #B2D490;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
}
h1 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 27px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0px;
  color: #00457D;
}
.left {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #C7E6FF;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 64px;
  margin-right: calc(50% - 450px);
}
.middle {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #DEF0FF;
  margin-top: 64px;
  float: left;
}
.right {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #C7E6FF;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 64px;
}
#footer {
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #57C449;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
p {
  color: #00579E;
}
#footer p {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 35px;
}
span {
  color: #D4EBFF;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  body {
    width: 95%;
  }
  .left {
    width: 60%;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .middle {
    width: 60%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    clear: both;
  }
  .right {
    width: calc(40% - 10px);
    margin-top: 64px;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  <title>My Resume</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>My <span>Resume</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    <h2>Left Column</h2>
    <ul>
      <p>Some Text</p>
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <h4>Right Column</h4>
    <ul>
      <p>Some Text</p>
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <h2>Сenter Column</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>Some Text</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Some Text</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both; border:none; border-radius: none;"></div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>© 2015 Me - the Programmer</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, almost perfect but the right column now have right margin.

Comment: No problem. Looks like it is due to the `body { width: 95%; }` rule in the media query. If you remove that rule it will align to the right edge.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that using flexbox

```css
div {
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#header {
    height: 52px;
    width: calc(100% - 16px);
    background-color: #B2D490;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
}
h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 27px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0px;
    color: #00457D;
}
.left {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #C7E6FF;
    margin-top: 64px;
}
.middle {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #DEF0FF;
    margin-top: 64px;
}
.right {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #C7E6FF;
    margin-top: 64px;
}
#footer {
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #57C449;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
p {
    color: #00579E;
}
#footer p {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    line-height: 35px;
}
span {
    color: #D4EBFF;
}

.columns{
  display:flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.left{
  order: 1;
}
.middle{
  order: 2;
}
.right{
  order: 3;
}

@media (max-width:980px){
  .middle{
    order: 3;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .right{
    order:2;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  <title>My Resume</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>My <span>Resume</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="left">
      <h2>Left Column</h2>
      <ul>
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <p>Some Text</p>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
      <h2>Сenter Column</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p>Some Text</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Some Text</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h4>Right Column</h4>
      <ul>
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <p>Some Text</p>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both; border:none; border-radius: none;"></div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>© 2015 Me - the Programmer</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank You, that's a great idea. But you missed the point a little bit. It should be like so: Left Column | Сenter Column and the Right Column below the Left column.

Comment: edited it, just add `flex-wrap:wrap;` to the div columns